# Simulating higher-kinded polymorphism with Object Algebra's in F#

Tags: f#, polymorphism, higher-order-types

In the paper [`Streams à la carte: Extensible Pipelines with
Object Algebras`](http://yanniss.github.io/algebras-ecoop15.pdf) Biboudis et al. outline a method of "emulating type-constructor ploymorphism" using object algebras.

I am trying to use this method to implement a higher-order example, similar to those described in [`Typed Tagless Final Interpreters`](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/lecture.pdf), within F# and have the following:

```
type App<'f,'a> = interface end

type ExprSYM<'f,'a> = 
  abstract litInt: int -> App<'f,int>
  abstract litBool : bool -> App<'f,bool>
  abstract add : App<'f,int> -> App<'f,int> -> App<'f,int>
  abstract gt : App<'f,int> -> App<'f,int> -> App<'f,bool>
  abstract conj : App<'f,bool> -> App<'f,bool> -> App<'f,bool>
```

The section relating to `Brand Freshness` describes nesting a class inside a type constructor. My translation to F# looks like:

```
type Eval<'a> =
  static member t = new obj()
  static member prj (app : App<Eval.t,'a>) = app :> Eval<'a>
  inherit App<Eval.t,'a>
```

However, I get the error `The type 't' is not defined`.

What is the correct way to write this in F#?

Comment: `Eval.t` is not a type but it is an instance of type `obj` so it cannot be used as a type argument in generic type. Also if you are going to inherit from interface you should use keyword `interface App<...> with`

Comment: Petr: I guess that is the essence of my question. In the referenced paper they use an anonymous inner class `t`. What I'm really asking is, how do I do this in F#?

Comment: F# doesn't support nested classes so you probably have to use another syntactic construction to model needed type behavior. Maybe using `modules` but I'm not sure because I haven't read referenced paper

Comment: I guess I'll have to read this more carefully but on first glance this should be your usual F-Algebra situations (here is a [nice Haskell article on this](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/bartosz/understanding-algebras)) - and I think you won't be able to express this construct well in F# as you cannot do something as the type-constructor `C<_>` (used in the linked article) easily. Maybe you can do some static-constraint magic to simulate this but I don't think you can get to the same - Ocaml has quite an advanced module system (at least as powerful as typeclasses) we do not have in F# sadly

Comment: https://github.com/pocketberserker/FSharp.Karma https://github.com/palladin/Higher

Comment: Mauricio Scheffer: This looks extremely interesting!! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Using a nested class doesn't particularly buy you anything; as the authors say

> In the Yallop and White technique for OCaml, this is ensured syntactically by the “freshness” of the brand, `t`, which is private to the type constructor. In Java, the property is ensured by convention: every subtype `S` of `App` has a locally deﬁned brand `t` and no subtype of `App<S.t, X>` other than `S` exists.

so you can obtain the same result with a different convention in F# (which doesn't support nested classes or static members within interfaces).  For example, you could create the subclass plus a separate marker class inside a module:

```
module Pull = 
    type t = class end
    type Pull<'t> = 
        inherit App<t, 't>
    let prj (app : App<t, 't>) = app :?> Pull<'t>
```

and then ensure that you don't use `Pull.t` elsewhere.